# Selenium WebDriverJS, cannot build webdriver for Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am having some trouble setting up Selenium WebDriverJS. My goal is to run selenium tests on Chrome browser using Javascript (node).

I am following the instructions on https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs as well as https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/wiki/GettingStarted

First I downloaded the chromedriver, and ran it on a terminal:

```
$ ./chromedriver
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.2) on port 9515
```

And then, I installed selenium-webdriver:

```
$ npm install selenium-webdriver
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver
selenium-webdriver@2.35.0 node_modules/selenium-webdriver
```

Then, I started node console and tried to build the webdriver instance

```
$ node
> var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')
undefined
> var driver = new webdriver.Builder().usingServer('http://localhost:9515/wd/hub').withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();
undefined
> 
timers.js:103
            if (!process.listeners('uncaughtException').length) throw e;
                                                                      ^
UnknownCommandError: unknown command: wd/hub/session
    at new bot.Error (/selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:109:18)
    at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (/selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/response.js:103:11)
    at /selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:133:20
    at /selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1178:15
    at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1438:20)
    at notify (/selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:328:12)
    at notifyAll (/selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:297:7)
    at fulfill (/selenium/
```

And now I am blocked. Can someone help me on this, please? What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Couple of things here.

1. By default, the chromedriver server handles commands at /, not /wd/hub.  So you should be able to do:

   ```
   new webdriver.Builder().usingServer('http://localhost:9515').build();
   ```
2. If you want the chromedriver to have the same signature as the standalone Selenium server, start it with `--url-base=/wd/hub`.
3. There's no need to start the chromedriver yourself - selenium-webdriver will do it for you if you request Chrome and omit a server location (make sure chromedriver can be found on your system `PATH`):

   ```
   new webdriver.Builder()
       .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
       .build();
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly. Now, if I may ask, is there a way to specify the location of the chromedriver in the code instead of using system PATH?

Comment: I had to dig the source code, but it was worth it!  
`new chrome.ServiceBuilder(PATH_TO_BINARY).build()` was the key :)