# Configuring Nightwatch to run tests on a standalone instance of Chrome

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I am trying to setup Nightwatch so that I do not have to use Selenium and instead point directly to an instance of Chrome on Linux, but I seem to be unable to connect to the chromedriver instance.

### nightwatch.json

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "",
  "globals_path" : "globals.js",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : false,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "./chromedriver"
    }
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "selenium_port"  : 9515,
      "selenium_host"  : "127.0.0.1",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
    "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After attempting to run a simple test suite, I get the following error

```
 ~/scripts/TestNightwatch$ nightwatch 

 [Test] Test Suite
 =====================

 Running:  Demo test Google Error processing the server response:  
 unknown command: wd/hub/session

 Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server

 Connection refused! Is selenium server started? { value: -1, error:
 'Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0' }
```

Have I not configured nightwatch properly to connect to Chrome? Am I missing any pieces of the puzzle?

Thanks in advance!

### globals.js

```
var chromedriver = require('chromedriver');

module.exports = {
  before : function(done) {
    chromedriver.start();

    done();
  },

  after : function(done) {
    chromedriver.stop();

    done();
  }
}
```

Comment: The answer offered by @user8185655 seems to have fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may be that Chromedriver is expecting commands at `/` instead of `/wd/hub`. To fix, start Chromedriver with `--url-base=/wd/hub`

Source: [Selenium WebDriverJS, cannot build webdriver for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389419/selenium-webdriverjs-cannot-build-webdriver-for-chrome) and https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/113

Comment: Yes, I execute ./chromedriver and the instance becomes available at port 9515.  `Starting ChromeDriver 2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.`

Comment: @pclaunch1 Perhaps the issue is that Chromedriver is not handling commands at the right location. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Okay, I changed my command to ./chromedriver --url-base=/wd/hub to start chromedriver and my tests are running now. Thanks @user8185655

Answer (score 0):

You need to start chromedriver in your external globals file. It looks like your config is correct. Just setup your `before` and `after` functions in the external globals module to start chromedriver.

```
before : function(done) {
  chromedriver.start();

  done();
},

after : function(done) {
  chromedriver.stop();

  done();
}
```

Take a look at the [Getting Started](http://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted/#standalone-usage) guide for more details.

Comment: Okay, I have already configured a globals.js file that I point to in my nightwatch.js file and I still get the same error. I've included my globals in an edit above. Is there a step I'm missing in utilizing my external globals module?